# How to calculate confidence bounds for this median unbiased estimate

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, unbiased-estimator

I am aiming to calculate confidence bounds for the median unbiased estimates, retrieved via the procedure described in Stock and Watson (1998). The authors that I am following state the following procedure:

*To compute this confidence interval, we use parameter estimates based on the
second-stage model with a time-varying trend growth and a constant natural rate
of interest to construct 10,000 simulated series of {y∗t , gt }. For each pair of simulated series we compute the exponential Wald statistic for an intercept shift in the first difference of y∗t .* (Holston, Laubach, and Williams, 2017).

However, I am puzzled on how to apply this procedure myself. Is there anyone that could help me with this issue?